# Homemade custard

Tags: eggs

I made homemade custard and refrigerated it right away.  (It contains soy milk, eggs, sugar-free maple syrup, and vanilla.  No cornstarch, flour, or preservatives.)  How long will it keep in the refrigerator?

Comment: Welcome to Seasoned Advice SE. :) Are you referring to a pudding like custard? Is there a lid on your container, or are you using plastic wrap?

Comment: Hard to tell as it seems to not have any real custard ingredients..  If it was a real custard I'd advise against freezing, as the texture is important and would be ruined